# getElementsByName('q')[0] returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a textbox to enlarge when focused

The relevant html code is

```
<input class="tbox" name="q" type="text" />
```

Since tbox is a catchall for every textbox in the page, I have to work with the name.

I tried this javascript

```
window.onload = init();
function init()
{
    var arr = new Array();
    arr = document.getElementsByName("q");
    var querybox = arr[0];
    querybox.addEventListener('onfocus', wasclicked, false);
    querybox.addEventListener('onblur', lostfocus, false);
}

function wasclicked(form)
{
    form.q.style['width'] = '500px';
}
    function lostfocus(form)
{
    form.q.style['width'] = '276px';
}
```

Debug console tells me I can't use addEventListener on an undefined.

I'm not familiar with javascript, so I tried [0].value as well to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several different issues.  First off, you need to use:

```
window.onload = init;   // assign function reference to .onload to call later
```

instead of:

```
window.onload = init();   // calls init() immediately and assigns return value to .onload
```

This is a very common JS mistake.  The way you have it, you are calling `init()` immediately (before the page has loaded) and assigning its return value to `window.onload` which won't work.

You want to assign a function reference to `window.onload`.  A function reference is the name of the function WITHOUT any parens after it.  Adding parens instructs the JS interpreter to execute the function NOW.  Assigning just the name puts a pointer to the function into `window.onload` so it can be called later when the `onload` event fires.

---

You also have to fix your event handler callbacks because the `form` is not what is passed to them.  The argument to an event handler is the `Event` object.  The object that caused the event will be in `this` or `event.target`:

```
function wasclicked(e) {
    this.style.width = '500px';
}

function lostfocus(e) {
    this.style.width = '276px';
}
```

---

And, the event names are "blur" and "focus" so you need to change this:

```
querybox.addEventListener('onfocus', wasclicked, false);
querybox.addEventListener('onblur', lostfocus, flase);
```

to this:

```
querybox.addEventListener('focus', wasclicked, false);
querybox.addEventListener('blur', lostfocus, flase);
```

---

Combining everything and doing a little simplification, the whole thing should look like this:

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    var querybox = document.getElementsByName("q")[0];
    querybox.addEventListener('focus', wasclicked, false);
    querybox.addEventListener('blur', lostfocus, false);
}

function wasclicked(e) {
    this.style.width = '500px';
}

function lostfocus(e) {
    this.style.width = '276px';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the code now runs fine except the width change doesn't happen. Using console.log(), I found the events trigger fine, so this might be a problem elsewhere. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user2444520 - It seems to work fine in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4w6cd/.  Just click in the input field or then in some other pane to see it change width.  I'm not sure what is different in your actual page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onload = init();
function init()
{
    var arr = document.getElementsByName("q");
    var querybox = arr[0];
    querybox.addEventListener('onfocus', wasclicked, false);
    querybox.addEventListener('onblur', lostfocus, flase);
}
function wasclicked(form)
{
    form.q.style['width'] = '500px';
}
    function lostfocus(form)
{
    form.q.style['width'] = '276px';
}
```

Comment: He wants to assign the `EventListener` to the `input` `text` element.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `onfocus` is the the event handler, but the event itself is `focus`.

```
function init()
{
    arr = document.getElementsByName("q");

    var querybox = arr[0];
    querybox.addEventListener('focus', wasclicked, false);
    querybox.addEventListener('blur', lostfocus, false);
}

function wasclicked(e)
{
    e.target.style.width = '500px';
}
function lostfocus(e)
{
    e.target.style.width = '276px';
}
window.onload = init();
```

As you can see, the event itself contains the elemet so there's no need to add any other variable.
Just know that `addEventHandler` won't work on all browsers.

Comment: See [JFriend00 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22317763/692942) for correct way to assign function references. `window.onload = init;`